# Looking for a way for a website to monitor a file on client side

Tags: java, security, file-upload, playframework, client-server

I am developing a website which basically crunches numbers from data files and display statistics.
These data files are on the client hard drive and the client can upload them to the server via the HTML upload functionality. 
This however requires the user to manually upload the files to update the statistics on the website.

I would like to know if there is a possibility for the website to automatically upload these files when they change. I can see the gapping security hole with skipping the user action, but is there a way for an user to share a specific directory from his drive with a website ? 
I am looking for something very lightweight and easy to configure as the user is not supposed to have any IT knowledge.

I am using Play! framework and the user can be on any OS with any browser.

Comment: Monitor the user reading the file, or monitor the user changing the file? The first is possible, the second is not (with web related technology).

Comment: Monitor the file changing (size or last modified date).
I was thinking maybe creating a little Java application that the user can run on his drive which push the files to the server every 10s.

Comment: From the user who's on any OS with any browser? Did you know there are OS's with browser's that don't have Java? Also, pushing the file every 10s isn't scalable.

Comment: It is a file about 100Kb, that should be quite quick

Comment: Is that per user, or per file, or both? And all users are on high speed low latency links? I'm guessing no.

Comment: Typically each user will have between 1 to 10 files (50KB each) to upload every few seconds. A user can only see the stats from his own files. And it does not have to be instant, it is ok if there are a few seconds latency between the file change and the actual upload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are saying yourself, there is no way to do this from a website for security reasons. Services that automatically share folders like, e.g, Dropbox does, do so by installing "real" applications client-side. I'd assume most users still consider this "lightweight" from their perspective, although it means more development work on your end. It also does not require significant IT knowledge.

Comment: What do you think of a little Java application that the user would run on his computer and which would upload the files when they change? Does it seem reasonable? I guess that is possible.

Comment: Possible but definitely not "little" if you want to get it right. You probably want to run this in the background as a service. And you have to ship a JRE as part of the installation bundle as Elliot said. Not every user will have java, and if you require them to install it, it will require IT knowledge again.

Comment: So what you are suggesting is to have the user synchronising his local folder with his Dropbox for example. And having my website monitoring changes on that dropbox?

Comment: That was not my suggestion. Dropbox was just an example how others do it. Your approach would work though, it saves you a lot of work, but it is kind of an evil hack :)

Comment: Ok, but the JRE bundle is not really something I wanted to do :) Using a third party application which already does all that could simplify the task for everybody, these guys probably solved all the OS related problems I could come across.